# Catching special characters with ncurses

Tags: linux, ncurses

I am currently working on a project for mapping every possible keyboard and mouse interrupt.
The mapping is done in linux environment and with ncurses library.

The question is how to catch the following keyboard keys :

Home
End
page up / down

when pressing those keys the terminal itself is catching them and the program itself cant see them (spent a few hours of configuration and found no solution yet)

pause/break (above page up in standard keyboard)
PrtScreen
Num Locked keys (0 to 9 and < . >).
Windows button

the following just not getting any response at all, neither from the terminal or the program.

Answer (score 1):

short: you cannot catch **all** keys with ncurses

long: the usual problems lie in a failure to initialize things properly:

- you probably forgot to call `keypad(stdscr,TRUE)` (or whatever window you might be using with `wgetch`).  That will allow an application to read any of the keys defined in the terminal description as an integer.
- If it is not in the terminal description, (n)curses will return the sequence of bytes which make up the key as sent from the keyboard.

That's two likely problems.  There are other keys (or combinations of keys) which the terminal will not send (in a way which makes distinct keyboard sequences).  For instance, using the <kbd>Control</kbd> key with other keys *may* change the sequence sent by the keyboard, or it may not.  To see this, use experiment with the control key with comma, period or the other punctuation keys in that area of the keyboard.